# Drag and drop multiple rows rows in angular

Tags: angular, grid

I can select single or multiple rows after pressing ctrl or shift key. Now once the rows are selected how can I move or drag multiple rows in angular. I don't want to use ag-grid.

```
onRowDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
    if (this.grid.areRowsDraggable) {
      const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
      if (target && target.dataset) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text', target.dataset.rowIndex);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Make a functional example in stackblitz for us.

Comment: what framework are you using ?

Comment: @StefaniToto Angular